# How to loop through specified files only?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently my code loops through each file in a directory and runs a macro if file name is in the range.

```
For Each folderIDX In PrimaryMergeFiles
Dim vTest As Variant
vTest = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(folderIDX.Name, _
    Worksheets("Table").Range("A1:A13"), 1, False)
If Not IsError(vTest) Then   ***RUN MERGEMACRO***
```

I want to change it so that it only loops through files with same names in range A1:A13

A1:A13 contains names 1.doc, 2.doc, 3.doc

PrimaryMergeFiles is a directory that contains word and pptx documents.

Comment: Your question is lacking detail so you might want to check [StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) so you can improve how you construct your question the next time and attract more answers. I provided an answer nevertheless which might solve your problem.

Comment: Let me try and understand this: Currently your code iterates over all files in PrimaryMergeFiles and if the file name is found in A1:A13 it runs a merging macro of some kind. What you would like to do is iterate over ONLY the files whose names are given in the specified range (instead of all files in `PrimaryMergeFiles`) and  run your merging macro on each of them in turn. It would help a lot if we had the data type of folderIDX and PrimaryMergeFiles and what sort of data is contained in A1:A13 e.g. File name, Folder name, full file path.

Comment: Yes Aiken, Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each folderIDX In PrimaryMergeFiles
Dim vTest As Variant
For Each vTest in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").Range("A1:A13")
If vTest.value = folderIDX then
End If
Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With Application
    Dim Flist As Variant
    Flist = .Transpose(Sheets("Table").Range("A1:A13"))
    For Each folderIDX In PrimaryMergeFiles
        If Not IsError(.Match(folderIDX.Name,Flist,0)) Then Call MERGEMACRO
    Next
End With
```

Is this what your trying? HTH.

Comment: From reading the question it seems like the OP wants to iterate over only the files that match the names in A1:A13 and always call a macro instead of iterating over all the files in `PrimaryMergeFiles` and then calling a macro if the name matches. In which case your answer has the same issue as the code in the question, you're still iterating over all of the files in `PrimaryMergeFiles`. I've asked the OP for more clarification on what they actually want.